# javascript contained in php not working on server but works when locallyhosted

Tags: php, javascript, forms

So I have this form page with method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" and I set my action to this php file. In this php file I have php code enclosed in  tags and then javascript code enclosed in   tags right after the php. I want it so that when I submit the form, both the php and javascript codes are ran. This works fine when I locally host it on my computer. However, it does not seem to work on the server I need to host it on. I added an alert() on the very first line of the javascript code and it does not run.  Does anyone know why this could be happening/ways I could debug this?
much Thanks.

(I don't think this is important but in addition the form is being submitted into an iframe to prevent page from changing)

-D
jQuery used to submit form:

```
          $("#saved_form").submit(function(e)
            {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.submit();
            ... }
```

Below is the php/javascript code:

```
  <?php
  include 'readFile2.php';
  readText();
  ?>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  alert("oh no");
  var errors = "<?= $_POST['error'] ?>";
  parent.window.saveLoad = 0;
  //checks if text file is entered
  if (errors == 1) 
  {
   alert("Please enter a text file");
  }
  else if (errors == 2)
  {
  alert("File must be text");
   }
  else
  {
  parent.window.saveLoad = 1;
  parent.window.saved_form = <?php echo json_encode($savedForm); ?>;
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: do you have some code we can see?

Comment: Check your browser's javascript console for errors? Missing files, bad paths, etc... all can lead to code not executing.

Comment: Have you tried using an AJAX call to the PHP file in the server instead of using the PHP file as the form action?

Comment: You do know javascript is usually executed on the client and PHP at the server?

Comment: Just a wild guess (due to lack of code): localhost supports <? and your host only supports <?php. Always make sure you use <?php

Comment: Make sure your server (ex: Apache) has PHP extension installed. Also, it'd be better if you show us some code.

Comment: -the javascript console shows no errors (however the "Oh no" popup works on localhost but does not show up when i load the code onto the server)
-the actual code is much much longer but see above for parts of it. PHP works fine (I see the text file being submitted into the iframe)
-not sure if this is best choice but I decided to use iframe instead of Ajax since I'm not getting anything from the database just reading a text file user submits

Comment: Maybe I'm just a "right tool for the right job" type of guy, but avoiding Ajax to do what Ajax is designed for seems counter productive.....don't fear Ajax!  Writing to a database isn't the only thing that Ajax is built for.  And judging by the amount of work it seems you've already committed, your shortcut seems anything but short to me.

Comment: Fair enough. Could you give me pointers as to how to do this? Do I use POST or GET  and how when I'm not getting anything from the database and only from a text file from a "file" type input. I have used Ajax and JSON in other places when I needed to simply get information from my database but reading a text file using Ajax frankly confuses me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This would be so much more appropriately done as an Ajax call to the php page.

For example:

```
$('#submitbtn).click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
         url: "readFile2.php",                              
         timeout: 30000,
         type: "POST",
         data: $('#saved_form').serialize(),
         dataType: 'json',
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
              alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)
         },
         success: function(data){   
              alert('it works.  You can do more on success of submit here');
         }                                                                                              
     });
 });
```

So, to summarize, the code above does an ajax call to a file called "readFile2.php"  It's posting serialized data from the form (essentially a javascript version of an HTML form submit, passing the values on the POST parameters to the PHP file)  It's expecting a return of json data (which could be changed to text, html, etc) and alerting "it works..." on success of the post.  The PHP file would have to accept the posted data, do something with it, and echo back what you want to return to the file.  I prefer sending a json string of the submit status so that I can tell my interface if something failed checks to prevent bad data getting in the DB.  You did have server side protection on your form submit....right?!?

Comment: this might work thanks. However, still a bit confused. If all I want to do is to read a text file a user uploads and return a string to javascript using an input type=file what would the POST parameters to the PHP file be?